# I accidently gave all my project files a .gz format, how to revert it?

Tags: centos, find, rename

So I've accidently gave all my files, php, js, html, css files a .gz ending, so they look like:

```
.bowerrc.gz
index.php.gz
main.css.gz
```

etc...

Using Centos 6.4, how can I revert back all the files?

I tried

> rename .gz '' *.gz

but it fails, nor find helped me as it doesn't do it recursively in all folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.gz" | while read file; do
  mv "${file}" "${file%%.gz}"
done
```

This *may* pick up files genuinely named ".gz" and rename them too, be careful.
Only does files.

Comment: It says "done" is undefined token. :/

Comment: Was missing a semi-colon. Sorry about that. Retry.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I've had to do something similar, I use a `for` loop with a `find`:

```
for file in `find . -name \*.gz`
do
  new=`echo $file | sed 's/.gz//'`
  mv $file $new
done
```

There's no guarantee this will actually work, since it's from memory, but that's the type of construct I would start with.

Comment: As long there are no files with spaces in their names, this will work fine.

Comment: I'd use `basename $file .gz` instead of sed, but the same approach